# How do I remove a substring from a value in an elasticsearch document using their devtools?

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-5

If each document has a value that is similar to:

> https://test.com/MODIF-RRS/D:/D-KGQLUL34TURWW-MODIF-AGENT04/_work/1179/s/test/code.cs
> and I want to remove the D:/D-KGQLUL34TURWW-MODIF-AGENT04/_work/1179/s/ part so I am left with https://test.com/MODIF-RRS/test/code.cs how would I do that?

I have a regex that works using an online tester

```
(D:/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/_work/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/s/)
```

but it gave me an error: invalid range: from (95) cannot be > to (93)

Answer (score 0):

I used char filter with your regex.

```
POST _analyze
{
  "char_filter": {
    "type":"pattern_replace",
    "pattern":"(D:/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/_work/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/s/)"
  },
  "text": "https://test.com/MODIF-RRS/D:/D-KGQLUL34TURWW-MODIF-AGENT04/_work/1179/s/test/code.cs"
}
```

Token

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "https://test.com/MODIF-RRS/test/code.cs",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 85,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(D:/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/_work/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/s/)
> invalid range: from (95) cannot be > to (93)
```

ASCII character 95 is `_` and ASCII character 93 is `]`.
The parser thinks `_-]` is supposed to be a range of characters (similar to `A-Z`) and is confused because the ASCII values left and right of `-` are not in ascending order.

As you do not want to specify a range there are all, try escaping the `-` characters with a leading `\`, so that the parser knows you mean a literal `-`, not a range of characters:

```
(D:/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/_work/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/s/)
```

Note: Depending on how you specify your regex (in JSON?), you may have to escape the `\` itself as well, so you'd have to write `\\-` instead of `\-`.

Alternatively it's usually possible to specify `-` as first character in the set, then the parser realizes it cannot be a range.

```
(D:/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/_work/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/s/)
```